# Firebug and .Net Application JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

Is there any way in which one can remove the "d" object from a .NET JSON string when viewing in firebug?

I am not entirely aware as to why it is added, however have discovered the following snippet which when added to a Jquery Ajax request allows my code to ignore it (if it is appended)...

```
dataFilter: function (data) {
                var msg = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                    return msg.d;
                else
                    return msg;
            }
```

However Firebug still shows this property thus rendering it not possible to view the JSON in a easy to use manner. i.e

[image: Example of how it is output]

Is it possible to not list the "d", but instead create a treeview with the other properties that are actually returned?

i.e.

```
   "TerminalNumber" : "0001",
 - "ListOfSomething" : [
      Value1, Value2, Value3
   ],
   "ObjectList" : {
       "KEY":"Value",
       "KEY2", "Value2"
   },
 + "CollapsedList" : []
   "SingleProperty" : "Hello"
```

Comment: for `why it is added ?` http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WCF to return the JSON, you could remove the "d" at its source by making these changes/additions to your web.config.

in your web.config, at a new endPointbehavior such as this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior_Plain">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>
```

and then bind your service to that new behavior like this:

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehaviorSvc" name="your-name-goes-here">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior_Plain" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="your-contract-name-goes-here" />
  </service>
```

If you are using legacy asmx web services, I think the way you are doing it now (in the JS) is the path of least resistance.